# Trigger a computed property when element is inserted

Tags: javascript, ember.js, computed-properties

i have an ember project with a service that gets the correct font size for an element based on its width. For responsive scaling.

Here is my code.

Element:

```
screenSizeService: service('screen-size'),
utilsService:      service('utils'),

portrait:  computed.readOnly('screenSizeService.portrait'),
landscape: computed.readOnly('screenSizeService.landscape'),

style: computed('screenSizeService.{width,height}', 'landscape', 'portrait', function()
{
    console.log('calculating');
    //Since the properties have to be consumed, get their values
    this.get('screenSizeService.width');
    this.get('screenSizeService.height');

    //Params = scale if it's landscape, scale if it's portrait, min font size, max and the parent to watch the width of
    return this.getFontSize(1.2, 1.2, 30, 60, this.$();
}),

getFontSize(landscapeScale, portraitScale, min, max, parent)
{
    const scale = (this.get('landscape')) ? landscapeScale : portraitScale;
    const fontSize = this.get('utilsService').scaleFontSize(parent, scale, min, max);
    return htmlSafe('font-size: ' + fontSize + 'px');
}
```

So this listens to the resize event and calculates every time it changes. This works really well except for when it initally loads.

On the initial load, The parent that im passing through doesnt have a width therfore cannot calculate its font size until the page is resized.

Here is my screen size service:

```
init()
{
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.get('resizeService').on('resize', this, this.screenSizeChange);
    this.screenSizeChange();
},

willDestroyElement()
{
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.get('resizeService').off('resize', this, this.screenSizeChange);
},

screenSizeChange()
{
    const width  = window.innerWidth;
    const height = window.innerHeight;

    this.set('width',  width);
    this.set('height', height);

    if (width >= height && !this.get('landscape'))
    {
        this.set('landscape', true);
        this.set('portrait',  false);
    }

    if (height > width && !this.get('portrait'))
    {
        this.set('landscape', false);
        this.set('portrait',  true);
    }
}
```

Lastly, My utils function that calculates the font size:

```
scaleFontSize(parent, scale, min, max)
{
    const parentWidth = (parent && parent.width()) ? parent.width() : null;
    if (!parentWidth) {return;}

    scale = scale || 1;
    min   = min   || 1;
    max   = max   || 1000;

    return Math.max(Math.min(parentWidth / (scale * 10), parseFloat(max)), parseFloat(min));
}
```

Would anyone know a possible way around this so it calculates on didInsertElement?

I have tried setting the style on didInsertElement, but then it doesnt change on resize. I think because im setting it twice.

Any help is appriciated

Comment: Maybe a [render modifier](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-render-modifiers) can help you

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use a component instead of service and wrap your content in that component. In this way you will be able to use `didInsertElement` hook.

Something like this, based on your code:

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import $ from 'jquery';
import { computed } from '@ember/object';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';

export default Component.extend({
  utilsService: service('utils'),

  style: computed('landscape', 'portrait', function() {
    return this.getFontSize(1.2, 1.2, 30, 60, this.$();
  }),

  getFontSize(landscapeScale, portraitScale, min, max, parent) {
    const scale = this.get('landscape') ? landscapeScale : portraitScale;
    const fontSize = this
      .get('utilsService')
      .scaleFontSize(parent, scale, min, max);
    return htmlSafe('font-size: ' + fontSize + 'px');
  },

  didInsertElement() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    //Element inserted, do calculations
    this.screenSizeChange();
    //Add resize handler
    $(window).on('resize', this._resizeHandler);
  },

  willDestroyElement() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    //It's important to remove resize handler on destroy, to avoid possible issues
    $(window).off('resize', this._resizeHandler);
  },

  _resizeHandler: computed(function() {
    const that = this;

    return function() {
      that.screenSizeChange();
    };
  }),

  screenSizeChange() {
    const width  = window.innerWidth;
    const height = window.innerHeight;

    this.set('landscape', width >= height);
    this.set('portrait',  width < height);
  }
});
```

BTW, you don't need `utils` service if it contains only static methods (simple functions). You can create `utils` directory under `app` and store utility functions there, and in your code do `import scaleFontSize from 'project-name/utils/scale-font-size'`;